# Pause/Resume/Seek mp4 on FFMPEG while transmitting to RTMP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, ffmpeg-php

I'm currently streaming an mp4 to an RTMP server just fine. I'm trying to figure out if I can pause the MP4 and Resume while staying connected to the RTMP server the entire time.

I'm streaming with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i myfile.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -preset:v ultrafast -f flv rtmp://myrtmp.server
```

The idea is that we are showing everyone a video that is in sync for everyone on our platform. If someone has a question, I would like to be able to pause the mp4. Once the question is answered, tell FFmpeg to resume playing the mp4

I'm currently using PHP, SOCKET, and obviously FFmpeg

Comment: I have the exact same problem and for the same reason, did you solve it by any chance?